# Django: Timeout when uploading videos to AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

What is the proper way to upload files to S3 from a DjangoApp hosted on Heroku?

> Video upload takes about 10 seconds and then I get the error.

Someone know of something like this, but in `gunicorn`:

https://vsoch.github.io/2018/django-nginx-upload/

**app:**

https://el-comercio-editoriales.herokuapp.com/predicas

Heroku is telling me this:

```
2019-07-23T02:53:52.878879+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/predicas" host=el-comercio-editoriales.herokuapp.com request_id=22b60bf7-949b-4f47-bfad-dabc33df9192 fwd="47.156.66.69" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30541ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I suppose I need to make an upload by chunks or something. Any hint would be appreaciated.

Comment: Are you using free plan heroku?

Comment: @AseelAshraf yes.

Comment: Maybe it is the answer